# How to make a pendulum swing along a circles circumference

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+, geometry, trigonometry

I am attempting to make a pendulum that will have user inputted string length. I am stuck on the issue of how to keep a "constant" string length, the issue is, as the string gets put at an angle the string stays at the same length but due to it being at an angle it shortens, I have tried to remedy this with this code:

---

```
If Angle > 0 Then
        If Angle < 50 Then
            x = Asin(Angle) * (LengthOfString + (Angle * 70))
            y = Acos(Angle) * (LengthOfString + (Angle * 70))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 270, 0, (270 + x), (0 + y))
        Else
            x = Asin(Angle) * (LengthOfString + ((100 - Angle) * 70))
            y = Acos(Angle) * (LengthOfString + ((100 - Angle) * 70))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 270, 0, (270 + x), (0 + y))
        End If
    Else
        Angle = Angle ^ 2
        Angle = Sqrt(Angle)
        If Angle < 50 Then
            x = Asin(Angle) * (LengthOfString + (Angle * 70))
            y = Acos(Angle) * (LengthOfString + (Angle * 70))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 270, 0, (270 - x), (0 + y))
        Else
            x = Asin(Angle) * (LengthOfString + ((100 - Angle) * 70))
            y = Acos(Angle) * (LengthOfString + ((100 - Angle) * 70))
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 270, 0, (270 - x), (0 + y))
        End If
        End If
```

---

Using the `(Angle * 70)` was a complete fluke, I first attempted to just do `LengthOfString + Angle` hoping that the length of that would fix it, this worked for a string length of 100 but when I extended this to 150 it ended up looking like a bell curve again.

I have no idea how I would fix this as it would have to be different for different length sizes.

Comment: I have now tried to change the above "70's" in the formulae with "LengthOfString" which fixes some issues around the higher angles but it makes angles between -10 < x < 10 make a weird w shape, but more rounded, when all 20 numbers are quickly flicked through

Comment: Note that `sin` and `cos` work with angles in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formulas are

```
        x = Sin(Angle) * LengthOfString 
        y = Cos(Angle) * LengthOfString
```

With  0 <= Angle <= 2*pi

Comment: When trying this it would jump about 10 degrees each increment, using Asin and Acos fixed this

Comment: Having given this another try now it just makes the run through of all numbers from -50 < x < 50 look like an upside down V

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this, what do you mean?

Comment: I have the swinging working, the issue is that due to how a diagonal line is shown in pixels, it is shorter than a line of the same length that is completely vertical. I need to know how this would be fixed and is kept looking the same length, even though the variable is changing or being edited, this would then give me a smooth swinging pendulum along a circles circumference.